# How to visualize data with validity period in Elasticsearch / Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana

I try to visualize in Kibana data which have validity period.
My documents look like that :

```
{
   "validityStart": "24-12-2016",
   "validityEnd": "01-01-2016,"
   "issueState": {
        "issueId":"123456"
        "status":"OPEN",
   }
};

{
   "validityStart": "01-01-2016",
   "validityEnd": "31-03-2016,"
   "issueState": {
        "issueId":"123456"
        "status":"CLOSE",
   }
};

{
   "validityStart": "30-12-2015",
   "validityEnd": "01-02-2016,"
   "issueState": {
        "issueId":"987654"
        "status":"OPEN",
   }
};

{
   "validityStart": "01-02-2016",
   "validityEnd": "05-05-2016,"
   "issueState": {
        "issueId":"987654"
        "status":"CLOSE",
   }
};
```

I indexed every attributes of this model in Elasticsearch as date or string indices.

I try to build an histogram chart in Kibana that shows how many issues are "OPEN" every day.

I have looked around "histogram agregation" or "date histogram agregation" features, but I can't figure out how to build an aggregation I could use in Kibana to build such a chart.

Any idea ?
Should I consider it as timeseries data and search a solution with Timelion ?

Comment: Are validityStart and validityEnd, type of date or string?

Comment: validityStart ans validityEnd are both dates. The structure of the document can change if if helps.

Comment: Which means, you need your chart using either one of those dates or both?

Comment: The chart uses both dates. The histogram has 1 bar per week. On each bar, the metric is the total number of isssues that was open on Monday 8:00PM. For a particular week, an issue is open when it has a state with status OPEN matching the following condition : (validityStart < Monday 8:00PM) AND (Monday 8:00PM < validityEnd)